# i facing uncaught error while implementing redux in react application using @reduxjs/toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Uncaught Error: The slice reducer for key "employee" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can use null in

**Root Store**

```
import {configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import  employeeReducer  from "./employee/employeeSlice"
import loginReducer from "./login/loginSlice"

export default configureStore({
  reducer:{
    employee:employeeReducer,
    login:loginReducer
  }
```

**Employee Slice**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"; 

 const employeeSlice= createSlice({
  name:'employee',
  initialValue:{},
  reducers:{
   editProfile:(state, action)=>{
    state.project = action.payload.projects
   },
   fetchProfile:(state, action)=>{
    return state
   }
  }
})

 export const {reducer , actions} = employeeSlice
 export const {editProfile } = actions
 export default reducer;
})
```

**loginSlice**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const loginSlice = createSlice({
 name:"login",
 initialState:{
   isLoading: false,
   isAuth: false,
   error:""
 },
 reducers:{
   loginPending:(state)=>{
     state.loginPending=true
   },
   loginSuccess:(state)=>{
     state.isLoading = false
     state.isAuth=true
     state.error=""
   },
   loginFail:(state, {payload})=>{
     state.isLoading=false
     state.isAuth=true
     state.error=payload
   }
  }
})

export const {reducer, actions} = loginSlice
export const { loginPending, loginSuccess, loginFail} = actions
export default reducer
```

[image: App crashed due to example image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello you made a tiny error

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"; 

 const employeeSlice= createSlice({
    name:'employee',
    initialValue:{}, // <----------------- it's initialState not initialValue :)
    reducers:{
        editProfile:(state, action)=>{
            state.project = action.payload.projects
        },
        fetchProfile:(state, action)=>{
            return state
        }
    }
})

export const {reducer , actions} = employeeSlice

export const {editProfile } = actions

export default reducer;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

With a single `initialState` you can use the shorthand of `Js` and leave it so ([modern js syntax:] without nameing the object `js` will expand it as needed):

```
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "authentication",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    login(state) {
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
    },
    logout(state) {
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
    },
  },
});
```

Or another option if you have multiple `slices` in the `store` & hence want to name each `initialState` in a different name

```
const initialAuthState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "authentication",
  initialState: initialAuthState,
  reducers: {
    login(state) {
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
    },
    logout(state) {
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
    },
  },
});
```

A third option would be (in any case if single or multiple slices), initialize per `slice`

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "authentication",
  initialState: {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    login(state) {
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
    },
    logout(state) {
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
    },
  },
});
```

But all together it's good practice to put different `silces` into seperate files.